# Get properties of datasource in CurrencyManager

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, data-binding

During design time, my control should expose all the fields available in data source. For example consider the following structure of data source

```
List<Data> dataSource = new List<Data>()
dataSource.add(new Data(){ Value = 1, Rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 10, 10)})
```

I want to bind my control with an inner property in the data source like `"Left"` property of Rectangle. I used the following code to achieve this

```
var prop = this.BindingContext[dataSource];
ArrayList result = (ArrayList)GetPropertiesList(prop.Current, string.Empty);
```

The code for GetPropertiesList method is below

```
private IList GetPropertiesList(object source, string parent)
        {
            ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList innerProperties = new ArrayList();
            Type sourceType = source.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = sourceType.GetProperties();
            if (parent != string.Empty)
                parent += "."; 
            foreach (PropertyInfo info in propertyInfo)
            {                
                object value = info.GetValue(source, null);                               
                if(value == null)
                    result.Add(parent + info.Name);
                else if (value is string || value is DateTime || value.GetType().IsPrimitive)
                    result.Add(parent + info.Name);
                else
                    innerProperties = (ArrayList)(GetPropertiesList(value, parent + info.Name));
            }
            if(innerProperties.Count > 0)
                result.AddRange(innerProperties);
            return result;
        }
```

This code fails when data is not added in the list object (`dataSource`).

Please share your thoughts and ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't wanna answer my question but I think it may help someone else.

After hours of searching I found that using property descriptor we can get a properties name, type, value, child properties, etc.., so I just modified my code in question a little.

The code in solution will populate all the available primitive, string and datetime properties (including primitive, string and date time properties of objects inside data source) in data source. So using this I can show inner properties in my designer.

The data source in my question will be shown in designer as follows:

```
Value
Rect.Left
Rect.Top
Rect.Width
Rect.Height
......
```

**Solution:**

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection members = dataSourceObject.GetItemProperties();
result = (ArrayList)GetPropertiesList(members, string.Empty);
```

Result will have all properties in array list. Looping through the array list I can get the name for individual properties

Code for function GetPropertiesList:

```
private IList GetPropertiesList(PropertyDescriptorCollection collection, string parent)
        {
            ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
            if (parent != string.Empty)
                parent += '.';
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in collection)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) || property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive)
                    result.Add(parent + property.Name);
                else
                {
                    result.AddRange((ArrayList)GetPropertiesList(property.GetChildProperties(), parent+ property.Name));
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

**Note:**

I'm only posting the code to show all the available fields in data source. The code for binding the fields to the control is different. Since, it's not relevant to the question I'm not posting them here.